# Does the mutex.lock need to end its lifecycle ahead of time?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a piece of Rust code.

```
use std::sync::Mutex;

struct Demo {
    a: Mutex<()>
}

fn return_demo() -> Demo {
    let d = Demo {
        a: Mutex::new(())
    };

    let _l = d.a.lock().unwrap();

    return d;
}

fn main() {
    return_demo();
}
```

The compilation error for the above code is as follows.

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `d` because it is borrowed
  --> src/bin/main15.rs:14:12
   |
8  |     let d = Demo {
   |         - binding `d` declared here
...
12 |     let _l = d.a.lock().unwrap();
   |              ---------- borrow of `d.a` occurs here
13 |
14 |     return d;
   |            ^ move out of `d` occurs here
15 | }
   | - borrow might be used here, when `_l` is dropped and runs the `Drop` code for type `MutexGuard`
```

I have two questions:

1. What does the error given by the compiler for this code mean?
2. Why can't the compiler automatically handle this situation, such as executing "drop" first and then returning?

Answer (score 4):

> What does the error given by the compiler for this code mean?

That the mutex is borrowed by the lock, and therefore can't be moved.

> Why can't the compiler automatically handle this situation, such as executing "drop" first and then returning?

Because this would chain the observable behavior of the program, so the compiler is not allowed to do that.

One may argue that releasing a lock earlier does not change the behavior of the program, but even if that's true (and it is not necessarily true - a program may depend on the lock being released at some time, for example because unsafe code is using data protected by it but not under the mutex) the compiler has no way to know that. `Drop` can do anything, for example printing, so executing it earlier is not allowed.